# Одинаковые символы regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Возможно ли с помощью regex найти одинаковые буквы в строке (встречаются несколько раз)? 
Пример: "Привет, как дела?" 
Совпадения: е, к, а.

Comment: проблема регулярки в том, что, чтобы найти пару "е", придётся покрыть кусок текста между ними.

Comment: Сергей, перенесите, пожалуйста, зелёную галку на ответ default locale, он более точно соответствует вопросу.

Comment: @vp_arth, нет, если использовать предпросмотр. Хм.. default locale его и использовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [просмотр вперед](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4) и применить выражение `(\p{L})(?=.*\1)`.

Пример кода:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{L})(?=.*\\1)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Привет, как дела?");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Само выражение по частям:

```
(\p{L}) — буква
(?=.*\1) —  та же буква (\1) в оставшейся части строки
```

Обратите внимание, что если буква встретится три или более раз, то выражение отловит каждое вхождение кроме последнего.

Comment: что-то я про lookahead-то и не вспомнил =)

Comment: @vp_arth бывает :) пожалуй, действительно, легче прописать код чем вспоминать его.

Comment: Буквы, встречающиеся более двух раз, будут выведены несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю искать их не регулярками:

```
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    String str = "Привет, как дела?";

    for(Character c: str.toCharArray()) { // набиваем хешмапу
      map.put(c,map.get(c)==null ? 1 : map.get(c) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(
      map.entrySet().stream()
         .filter(cnt -> Character.isLetter(cnt.getKey()) && cnt.getValue() > 1) // фильтруем
         .map(e -> e.getKey())
         .collect(Collectors.toList()) // собираем список
    );
```

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/OGZ74858)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае можно найти первую совпадающую подстроку регуляркой "([а-яА-Я]).*\1". Регулярка найдет "ет, как де" а дальше провяться будет только оставшийся текст. Логичнее делать циклом.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ похож на [ответ @defaultlocale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825286/178988), но:

- если символ встречается более двух раз, он выводится только единожды
- проверяются не буквы, а любые символы
- порядок вывода - по предпоследнему вхождению (`ba` и `zy` в примере)

https://ideone.com/UimHaP

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)(?=((?!\\1).)*\\1(?!.*\\1))");

    for (Matcher m = p.matcher("abacaba dx xyzzzyy"); m.find(); ) {
      System.out.print(m.group());
    }
  }
}
```

```
ba xzy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class common {

public static void main(String args[]){

    String line = "Привет, как дела? Yeah, amazing! How about you?"; //сама строчка.

    int []arr = new int[1150]; // Array на 1150 символов, чтобы можно было записать значения в ASII английские и русские буквы
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
            int index = (int) line.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
            if ((index > 96 && index < 123) || index > 1000 ) {
                arr[index]++;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("Часто повторяющиеся буквы");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > 1) {
            System.out.println("character: "+ Character.toString ((char) i) + " " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
(е|к|а)(?=.*\1?)
```

Результат: Прив**е**т, **как** д**е**л**а**?

Comment: Задача стоит найти **любые** буквы, которые встречаются более одного раза. А не только е, к, а.

Comment: Любые буквы (кирилица) - ([а-яА-яёЁ])(?=.*?\1) Здесь правда последние повторяющиеся буквы не будут подсвечены